# Lucene: Why the search cost increase with the page increase?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch cluster with 1G cache for each machine. I configured the searcher that 5000/perpage.

When I search page 3, it cost about 400ms. But when I search page 300, the cost increased to more than 5000ms! About 60% cache was free at this situation.

Why the cost increased more than 10 times?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to page that far, Elasticsearch has to retrieve all previous pages, just to discard them at the end. A search with `from: 1000, size: 100` is equivalent to a search with `from: 0, size: 100100`, only that you just get the last 100 results. That also means, that every document has to be scored, which is a potentially expensive operation.

There was a recent optimization, that should improve performance in such cases, when you use a [scroll search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#search-request-scroll), see this [github issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4940).

Comment: +1 good explanation and great heads up on the improvement that has just been pushed, although it relates to scroll search and not ordinary search. I think there are a few too many zeros though ;) the actual size of the priority queue coming from each shard is `from + size`, where from is the position of the first interesting document, not the page number.

Comment: Ah, yes. I guess i was going for something like page 1000 instead of from